# Через минуту бот на Heroku крашится с ошибкой 503

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, heroku, развертывание, deploy

Столкнулся с проблемой. Залил телеграмм бота на *Heroku*. Сделал *Deploy*. Работает в течение минуты, а потом в консоли выдает

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

Но на протяжении минуты работает идеально, потом вот с такой ошибкой падает. Как можно убрать эту ошибку и в чём вообще причина?

Comment: Причины могут быть совершенно различные, гадать тут смысла не имеет. Пожалуйста, опишите, что вы уже пытались сделать для выяснения и решения проблемы и к чему это привело, тогда вам смогут помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Мой *Procfile* выглядел так:

```
web: node bot.js
```

Вместо этого поставил в код файла:

```
bot: node bot.js
```

Всё. Теперь работает постоянно.